# problem with a trailhead Visualize Your Data with the Lightning Dashboard Builder

Tags: dashboard, trailhead

I have created reports and dashboard as perr the this link ( https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trails/force_com_admin_beginner/modules/lex_implementation_reports_dashboards/units/lex_implementation_reports_dashboards_visualizing_data)

when i tried to check it show

> Challenge Not yet complete... here's what's wrong:  Could not find a
>   component in the 'Big Deals' dashboard with the title 'Opportunity
>   Stages'.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

switch to lightning experience and click check challenge again it will work.Happened with me also

Answer (score 0):

Make certain the Dashboard is named `Big Deals` (check your spelling) and that your component is also named and spelled correctly as `Opportunity Stages`. Typos are frequently common causes of these types of error messages.

Comment: you can see screenshot.. i have mentioned correct spelling with correct case

Comment: Those are labels. Go and look in your org to see how they're declared in the Dashboards and that all other settings are correct too. I always copy/paste names for settings from the challenge into my org. If that doesn't work, try duplicating it in another org as you could have an issue with your org that's preventing it from validating. Unfortunately that happens at times. BTDT.